# How could i find whether it is successful or declined transaction in balanced payments

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, balanced-payments

I am trying to implement a mechanism that provides the facility of credit amount to user bank account using balanced payments.

I just followed the api reference provided by the balanced payment api and its works fine without any exceptions. In the balanced payment api docs they mentioned credit will done after 2-3 business days.

In my application registered users will have some amount so that they can use that money to perform remaining activities in my application.

Suppose if a user enters the information regarding his account is structurally correct i.e. valid routing number,account number etc. but if the routing number and account number does not have any relationship between them due to type error or intentionally they test.

At this point i need to deduct some amount from user account balance in our application. But balanced payment is giving response status with pending for both successful and declined transactions.

How could i find whether it is successful or declined transaction based on that i will take a step to deduct amount from user account balance or just leave it alone?

Does balanced payment provides any way to overcome this situation or any standard techniques to get rid of this?

Comment: Ask the API vendor, there's no way we can know.

Answer (score 2):

When creating a credit, the [credit.succeeded](https://docs.balancedpayments.com/current/api?language=bash#event-types) event is triggered when the bank says that the it has received the money.  However the state might change at a latter time to [credit.failed](https://docs.balancedpayments.com/current/api?language=bash#event-types) when the bank actually tells us that there is an issue.

The best way to deal with this is assume that it worked until you get a credit.failed event.